# Extraction of datatype and label names from rdflib.term.Literal

Tags: python, rdf, owl, ontology, rdflib

I am executing sparql query through python rdflib like

```
r=sparql.prepareQuery('SELECT ?label WHERE { <%s> rdfs:label ?label . }'%i)
```

My aim is to get the labels for the concepts in this way.
As a result I get something like this:

```
rdflib.term.Literal(u'primary phloem sieve cell', datatype=rdflib.term.URIRef(u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'))
```

From this I want to extract the label and data type.(ie  primary phloem sieve cell and string respectively for this case)
I am using  the

```
if type(o) == rdflib.term.Literal:
    output.append(o.toPython())
```

Where

```
o= rdflib.term.Literal(u'primary phloem sieve cell', datatype=rdflib.term.URIRef(u'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string'))
```

But it is not working.
I am new to rdflib .
Does anyone know how I can do that?

I know that I need to convert the result to string for label but what if the datatype is not string and I want to fetch the datatype

Comment: Please format your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.As the type of the query result i.e o is 'rdflib.query.ResultRow'
and o[0] is class 'rdflib.term.Literal'.Hence the if condition was not working.
Removing the if condition worked for me and for the data type I need to execute another sparql query .